# App Engine with subdomains displaying IPs rather than content

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, cloudflare

I have configured the App Engine to use a custom domain that I have on CloudFlare. I added the TXT record for verification and all the A and AAAA entries with the given IP addresses.
I have also added 2 CNAME entries that matches the name of 2 services that I have deployed (web and api). I have done this on App Engine settings and in the CloudFlare dashboard.
When I try to go to web.mydomain.com or api.mydomain.com on both cases rather than seeing the content I receive a text response showing a list of IP addresses, and the content served by the Google Frontend (according to the response headers).
Is there any additional configuration I need to do for this to work?

Both services works fine if I access them using the default domain provided by Google (appspot.com)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that I had to deploy the dispatch.yml file in order for this to work

```
dispatch:
  - url: "api.mydomain.com/*"
    service: api
  - url: "web.mydomain.com/*"
    service: web
```